# Asynchronous with indexeddb problems

Tags: asynchronous, indexeddb

I am having problem with a function in IndexedDB, where I need to change the status of some meetings. The Search feature which meetings are checked by grabbing the ID of each one of them, soon after I A `for()` where I retrace the vector that contains the ids for each database access do I get a different passing the id of the time. The following code example:

```
      var val = [];
  var checkbox = $('input:checkbox[class^=checkReunioes]:checked');
  if(checkbox.length > 0){
    checkbox.each(function(){
      val.push($(this).val());
    });
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++){
    var transaction = db.transaction(["tbl_REUNIOES"], "readwrite").objectStore("tbl_REUNIOES");
    var request = transaction.get(val[i]);
    request.onerror = function(event) {
      alert("BAD");
    };
    request.onsuccess = function(event) {

      var data = request.result;

      data.FLG_STATU_REUNI = 'I';

      var codigo_igreja = localStorage.getItem("igreja");
      var dataJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
      enviarFilaSincronismo("tbl_REUNIOES", "U", dataJSON, " WHERE COD_IDENT_REUNI = '" + val[i] + "' and COD_IDENT_IGREJ = '" + codigo_igreja + "'");

      var requestUpdate = transaction.put(data);
      requestUpdate.onerror = function(event) {
        alert("OK");
      };
      requestUpdate.onsuccess = function(event) {
        $("#listReunioes").html("");
        serchAll(w_key_celula);
      };
    };
  }
```

In my view the problem is occurring due to be a bank indexeddb asynchronous, it passes to the next search, even before the first stop. 
But how can I do to confer this ? 
What is the good practice for something in this case ?.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are inexperienced with writing asynchronous code, a good general rule to consider is to never define functions inside loops. Do not set request.onsuccess to a function from within the for loop.
2. You can perform multiple get and put requests on the same transaction when you do not expect the individual requests to fail for data-related reasons, such as the violation of a uniqueness constraint of an index, or because you are performing many thousands of requests on the same transaction and reaching processing limits.
3. You might find that using IDBObjectStore.prototype.openCursor together with IDBCursor.prototype.update is more convenient than using IDBObjectStore.prototype.get and IDBObjectStore.prototype.put.
4. Your example code indicates that a successful get request means that data was retrieved, when in fact, this is not what actually happens. A successful get request just means that a request occurred without errors (e.g. against an object store that exists, against a database that is not blocked by other requests, against a database connection that is still valid). It does *not* mean that an object matched your get request query. You should be checking for whether the request's result object is defined, and use that check as a determination of whether an object matched your get query, and not simply that a successful request occurred.
5. You might want to spend more time organizing your code into smaller functions that use clearer names. Your example code is difficult to read.
6. It looks like you are using some type of global db variable. If you are not well experienced with writing asynchronous code, avoid using a global db variable. There is no guarantee the db variable will be defined and open when you decide to access it, which could lead to an unexpected error.

Comment: In reality the problem is found in points 3 and 4, the rest is confirmed that is functioning perfectly, would have as its response indicate a correct method to make the process ? Trying to maintain the maximum the code before programd ?